# Saving a Single int into NSdefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've been searching around for tutorials on how to save certain things to NSuserdefaults but have only found stuff mostly dealing with arrays and strings. Can anyone lead me to or give some person knowledge about saving and loading a int. For my application I have my int highScore = 0; but I want it to save this int into your NSuserdefaults so when my game loads back up it displays your current high score you recently achieved.

Answer (score 12):

```
int highScore = 0;

// write
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highScore forKey:@"someKey"];

// read
highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"someKey"];
```

Comment: where should I put the write and read at in my code. Should one be called when my superview loads.. and the other when submitting the highscore ? I tried it and didn't get in errors but it wouldn't save the data.

Comment: Write when submitting the high score and read when loading view that shows the high score to the user (maybe in -viewDidLoad or -viewWillAppear).

Comment: I think you need to use NSInteger type for highScore

Answer (score 2):

Save it as a `NSNumber`, using `-[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore]`.

Answer (score 0):

**NSUserDefaults** can only handle property list objects.  Property lists objects must be one of the following types **NSArray**, **NSDictionary**, **NSString**, **NSData**, **NSData** and **NSNumber**.

**NSUserDefaults** has a number of helper methods that convert c numeric types to and from **NSNumber** objects automatically.  The **setInteger:forKey:** and **integerForKey:** and the helper methods for integers.  These methods expect the integers to be of type **NSInteger**.  **NSInteger** is not an object.  It is just a typedef for **long int**.  Your code is defining highScore as an **int**. This could be the cause of the problem.

I prefer to convert c numeric types to **NSNumber** objects and save the object.  Although this seems like extra work, this can simplify your code since every thing returned by **NSUerDefaults** will be an object and can be processed in a uniform way.